# AWS Network load balancer health check is failing for ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, nlb

I have created a ECS service to deploy a spring-boot application. I have added the target group to Network load balancer by specifying the load balancer name while creating container for this service in aws ecs console.

Now When I check the health status of that target group it is continuously doing registration and deregistration with different IP addresses. I checked the security group also, it has allowed all ports and IPs.

Can anybody help here what could be the issue of not coming "healthy" status of the target group.

Please find attached screenshot of ECS service, health check status and security group used.

[image: ECS service]

[image: Screenshot of health status of NLB]

[image: Screenshot of security group used while creating container]

[image: Target group health check settings]

[image: Screenshot of target group attached to ECS]

[image: creation of task definition]

[image: screenshot once task definition created]

[image: ECS service logs]

[image: Cluster dashboard screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of linking target group while creating service]

[image: Task definition screenshot 1]

Comment: Please include the target group's health check settings in your question

Comment: @MarkB I have attached the same. I have used the by-default setting of health check. There was an option in increase the health check grace period.  I had even checked it by increasing it from 0 to 2 minutes, but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Have you checked logs? Can you post those?

Comment: @priyadhingra19 Understand the difference between Host Port & Container Port. Looks like you are trying forward the traffic to container on 80 port according to target group settings but your task definition is bringing container on 10001 for both Host((look at the targets registered and their port) & Container(look at the Container Port on Load Balancing on Service). You have 2 options. 1) Update/create target group to forward the traffic on 10001 instead of 80. or 2) update the task definition to bring container port on 80 instead of 10001.

Comment: @Imran As per my understanding , VoiceX-NLB is the name of the Network load balancer which has one listener with listener id TCP:10001. Once it receive any traffic with this post it would forward it to target group named ecs-VoiceX-VoiceX-service . We have associated this target group with our ecs container. Please refer last screenshot for this.

Comment: @Imran This is my first ECS service. my understanding could be wrong. I have just followed these links to create ECS with fargate with NLB

I have followed following links for references
https://medium.com/containers-on-aws/using-aws-application-load-balancer-and-network-load-balancer-with-ec2-container-service-d0cb0b1d5ae5
As per this link, by default target group created with port 80. we should ignore it. we would set the correct port once we link ecs container with NLB.
https://www.systems-plus.com/using-amazon-api-gateway-to-route-requests-to-restful-microservices-in-amazon-ecs/.

Comment: @Imran Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @RodrigoM I have checked service logs. It is fine ,spring boot service is up. I was not able to find any logs related to health check. Do you have any idea how can i find them ?

Comment: @priyadhingra19 I am not worried about default target group(80), its irrelevant here and you can delete it, as long as your hitting NLB with 10001 port(ex: `http://nlbhostname:10001/`). what port is your spring boot coming up?. Go to `VoiceX:1` task definition and provide the `Port Mapping` details?. `Host <--> Container` Mapping. Your Target Group(`ecs-VoiceX-VoiceX-service`) Port should match the Spring Boot App Container Port.

Comment: @Imran . Thanks a lot for replying back. I have checked the port mapping in cluster. While creating I had only mentioned port mapping 10001 and it was not showing any option to add host mapping because fo selecting network mode- awsvpc. After running my container it dynamically assign 10001 to host mapping also. 
I have attached both the screenshot what i chosen at the time of creation of task definition and what host mapping assigned to it after creation of task definition.
Also attached service logs.

Comment: @priyadhingra19 awsvpc mode brings the container on host with same port as container port. alright. Perform one of the option I gave initially. Re-create the target group `ecs-VoiceX-VoiceX-service` with port as 10001 instead of 80 and attach back to the service(you might need to re-create the service again!!).

Comment: @Imran Alright I'm trying this option as well. I have attached few screenshots. Please check them as well if they could help you to give some hint about the issues. Thanks again. I'm really struggling with this issue.

Comment: @priyadhingra19 wait!!!. You are bringing the spring boot container on 8080 port then your container port should be 8080 not 10001. so you need to update the target group to 8080 port instead of 10001.

Comment: @Imran Oh. Yes you are right. This could be the issue. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @Imran Wow. It worked. Many many many thanks :-). I really would not able to find that issue. Thanks again

Comment: @priyadhingra19 great!!. I will add my observations as answer. if you are ok then you can accept and upvote it!!

Comment: @Imran Sure . I will definitely do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed over comments, here is the issue with your setup.

1. You are bringing the spring boot container on `8080` port so ECS Task Definition `Container Port` should be 8080(not 10001).
2. Your `Container Port` & `Target Group` port should be in sync irrespective of `Host Port` or `NLB Listener Port`. So re-create the Target Group with Port as 8080 and re-create the ECS service attached to updated Target Group.
3. Finally, it looks like your traffic is more of HTTP/HTTPS based so I would be probably suggest to use `ALB(Application Load Balancer)` instead of `NLB`. NLB works for all the TCP ports but you will get more advantages of using ALB for HTTP/HTTPS based traffic. I am not sure of your application fully so its a mere suggestion!!.

Comment: My usecase is spring boot application would expose some REST apis. These REST apis would be consumed by mobile app and Alexa skill. I'm thinking of putting AWS Api gateway before ECS. I have followed the references mentioned in above comment. They suggested me to use NLB if you want to use api gateway with ECS. Api gateway allow me to put api level throttling . Do you have any suggestion over it ?

Comment: @priyadhingra19 ohh!!. Go ahead with just NLB if you want to integrate API Gateway, you should be good. I thought you are going to expose NLB directly to consumers so I suggested ALB.